# How do I upgrade my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04, lts

How do I upgrade my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS? My update manager tells me my Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.

I did pressed `Alt+F2` and typed `update-manager-d` but still had no luck. I could really use some help with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to upgrade to 12.04 LTS instead of 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Did you try to apt-get upgrade

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: IMHO, upgrades are not an option here. You need to backup and reinstall. Ubuntu 12.04 only has 7 months of support left to it, which makes 14.04 or 16.04 better options.

Comment: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) -- not a dupe yet until you make up your mind whether to upgrade to 12.04, 16.04 or do a fresh (re)install of 16.04 (better option).

Comment: @karel will the link help to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04?

Comment: When I read the help guide, it said I could not skip. I have to go from a 10.04 LTS to a 12.04 LTS until I reach the newest version. If I misunderstood, please tell me the correct way.

Comment: @Anwar: Yes it should. The target upgrade release 12.04 is still supported so that should be no problem either.

Comment: Is your machine dual booted with windows or just ubuntu based?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps to upgrade your system from  10.04 server to 12.04

Follow these steps.

1.Open terminal press ctrl+alt+t, then enter these commands.
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade

2.Install update-manager-core
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

3.Edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts

4.Launch the upgrade tool, and follow the on-screen instructions:

sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: Step 2 will fail because the package repositories for 10.04 are offline and were moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com.